# How can I format a table to look nice?

Tags: output-formatting, list-manipulation, alignment

I have this code, but I would like to see the results well formatted.
How can I obtain a well formatted data with alignment similar to this one?

[image: Example table]

Instead, I obtain the result you see here (click to enlarge):

[image: Screenshot of code and table output]

---

Here is the code wherein I attempt to obtain a well formatted results:

```
itmax = 10;
tolerancia = 0.2;
alfa = (-1 + Sqrt[5])/2;
ttheta[Lambda_] = Lambda^2 + 2*Lambda;
a = -3;
b = 5;
La = a + (1 - alfa)*(b - a) // N;
Mu = a + alfa*(b - a) // N;
tthetaLa = ttheta[La];
tLacalc = "*";
tthetaMu = ttheta[Mu];
tMucalc = "*";
Print["iteración_k   |   a_k    b_k   |   Lambda_k     Mu_k   |   \
theta(Lambda_k)  theta(Mu_k)"];
Do[
  L = b - a;
  Print[i, "   |   ", a, "     ", b, "   |  ", La, "     ", Mu, 
   "   |  ", tthetaLa, tLacalc "      ", tthetaMu, tMucalc ];
  If[tthetaLa > tthetaMu,
   If[b - a < tolerancia, Break[]];

   a = La;
   La = Mu;
   Mu = a + alfa (b - a);
   tthetaLa = tthetaMu;
   tLacalc = " ";
   tthetaMu = ttheta[Mu];
   tMucalc = " ";,

   b = Mu;
   Mu = La;
   La = a + (1 - alfa) (b - a);
   tthetaMu = tthetaLa;
   tMucalc = " ";
   tthetaLa = ttheta[La];
   tLacalc = "*";
   ]
  , {i, 1, itmax}
  ];
solucionestimada = (Mu + La)/2;
valorestimado = ttheta[solucionestimada];
Print["The stimated solution is ", solucionestimada, 
  " where functions value is ", valorestimado];
```

Comment: Have a look at [`Grid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Grid.html) or [`TableForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TableForm.html) and get rid of all your `Print` statements - the *Mathematica* workflow offers much better solutions.

Comment: @Yves Klett Yves Klett Thank You. I´m agree you, but i think that Grid and TableForm are for Arrays, and i prefer don´t use arrays, because with major algorithms i don´t want to use many memory.

Comment: Mathematica generally has little need of `Print` statements. Focus your code on creating the data you want as a result, then, as Yves has suggested, you can output that data in almost any form you desire using functions like `Grid` or `Table`. You may want to look at the functional programming features of Mathematica which would help make your code much more concise.

Comment: However you generate your data, you should abstract the data from any formatted output. If you want to display it in a notebook in readable textual form, memory should (presumably) not be an issue. How many elements do you want to display?

Comment: @image_doctor Ok. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Yves Klett i prefer make a code and not store all the data, because i think that is not good costume, if you can avoid it. Only if you can avoid it. Thank You Very Much

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is something not far from your example:

[image]

Collecting data using `Sow` and `Reap` as shown by [cormullion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/61/cormullion):

```
Sow[{i, a, b, La, Mu, Row@{tthetaLa, tLacalc}, Row@{tthetaMu, tMucalc}}]
```

We get:

```
dat =
{{1, -3, 5, 0.0557281, 1.94427, Row[{0.114562, "*"}], Row[{7.66874, "*"}]}, {2, -3, 
  1.94427, -1.11146, 0.0557281, Row[{-0.987578, "*"}], Row[{0.114562, " "}]}, {3, -3, 
  0.0557281, -1.83282, -1.11146, Row[{-0.306418, "*"}], 
  Row[{-0.987578, " "}]}, {4, -1.83282, 0.0557281, -1.11146, -0.665631, 
  Row[{-0.987578, " "}], 
  Row[{-0.888198, " "}]}, {5, -1.83282, -0.665631, -1.38699, -1.11146, 
  Row[{-0.850238, "*"}], 
  Row[{-0.987578, " "}]}, {6, -1.38699, -0.665631, -1.11146, -0.941166, 
  Row[{-0.987578, " "}], 
  Row[{-0.996539, " "}]}, {7, -1.11146, -0.665631, -0.941166, -0.835921, 
  Row[{-0.996539, " "}], 
  Row[{-0.973078, " "}]}, {8, -1.11146, -0.835921, -1.00621, -0.941166, 
  Row[{-0.999961, "*"}], 
  Row[{-0.996539, " "}]}, {9, -1.11146, -0.941166, -1.04641, -1.00621, 
  Row[{-0.997846, "*"}], Row[{-0.999961, " "}]}}
```

And produce the table shown above with:

```
headings = {"k", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\"a\", \"k\"]\)", 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\"b\", \"k\"]\)", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\"\[Lambda]\", \"k\"]\)", 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\"\[Mu]\", \"k\"]\)", 
   "\[Theta](\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\"\[Lambda]\", \"k\"]\))", 
   "\[Theta](\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\"\[Mu]\", \"k\"]\))"};

headings2 = Item[Style[#, Italic], Alignment -> 1] & /@ headings;

divs = # -> AbsoluteThickness@#2 & @@@ {{1, 3}, {2, 2}, {-1, 2}};

Grid[
 dat ~Prepend~ headings2,
 Dividers -> {{}, divs},
 Alignment -> ".",
 BaseStyle -> FontFamily -> "Calibri"
]
```

(Sorry about the horrible looking code for `headings`; it is simply a list of formatted strings in the Front End.)

---

As requested, here is complete code to generate the `dat` expression shown above:

```
itmax = 10;
tolerancia = 0.2;
alfa = (-1 + Sqrt[5])/2;
ttheta[Lambda_] := Lambda^2 + 2*Lambda;
a = -3;
b = 5;
La = a + (1 - alfa)*(b - a) // N;
Mu = a + alfa*(b - a) // N;
tthetaLa = ttheta[La];
tLacalc = "*";
tthetaMu = ttheta[Mu];
tMucalc = "*";
dat =
 Reap[
  Do[L = b - a;
   Sow[{i, a, b, La, Mu, Row@{tthetaLa, tLacalc}, Row@{tthetaMu, tMucalc}}];
   If[tthetaLa > tthetaMu, If[b - a < tolerancia, Break[]];
    a = La;
    La = Mu;
    Mu = a + alfa (b - a);
    tthetaLa = tthetaMu;
    tLacalc = " ";
    tthetaMu = ttheta[Mu];
    tMucalc = " ";, b = Mu;
    Mu = La;
    La = a + (1 - alfa) (b - a);
    tthetaMu = tthetaLa;
    tMucalc = " ";
    tthetaLa = ttheta[La];
    tLacalc = "*";], {i, 1, itmax}]
 ][[2, 1]]
```

It will be necessary to read the documentation for `Sow` and `Reap` to understand this.  Also, `func @ arg` is equivalent to `func[arg]`, I just prefer to use the former sometimes.  The `[[2, 1]]` after `Reap` is a syntax for `Part`, and is used to extract (only) the sowed expression from the returned value of `Reap`. (Again, see the documentation for `Reap`.)

Comment: I like very much your answer. Ilove it, but i don´t know how i must modify my code to obtain this. I don´t know how i use Reap Sow , to make the table.

Could you attach the .nb file, or a .txt. to learn this?.

Thank You very much.

Comment: @MikaIke Sorry, I thought the Accepted answer covered this.  I'll add an example to my answer.

Comment: i understand the essence, but my problem is colllecting data with Reap Sow (i don´t know about this before cormullion talks about it). I think that it´s very usefull but untill now, i can´t use it correctly in my code. So i can obtain a table.

Comment: The firts time i heard avbout Reap Sow was in the @cormullion message, and i think that it´s usefull.

Comment: @MikaIke Does my example adequately illustrate how to use this in your application?

Comment: Yes the example illustrates me how and where i must put Reap Sow. Now, we are... with another little problem The MAthematica tells me http://img705.imageshack.us/img705/2900/snap2005.png  but... the Rep Sow... :-) i understand where i have to type it. Thano You

Comment: @MikaIke Sorry, that's my mistake.  I was typing part of this here, outside of the Front End, so I didn't test my own code.  I put the assignment `dat =` on the wrong line!  I'll fix it now.

Comment: Yes i change that errata, and i can understand that, but... i test in my computer and have no table, as you can see here. Could you revise where is my error?, https://www.dropbox.com/s/qdea4esdzw2kio8/Stack_formatted.zip Thank You

Comment: @MikaIke Two changes only: (1) You must include the code: `[[2, 1]]` following `Reap` as shown at the very bottom of my answer above, as this extracts the part needed; otherwise you still have the `Null` that is the return value of a `Do` loop (every evaluation returns a value; the ones that appear to return nothing return the reserved symbol `Null` which the Front End does not print).  (2) Remove the `;` following the `Grid` code so as not to suppress output.

Comment: PERFECT!!! Simply perfect!! i´m impressed by you, and cormullion. REALLY IMPRESSED.

Answer (score 9):

*Mathematica* doesn't do the slickest table formatting in the world, but you can do quite well, with some effort.

[image: table]

To get something like this, you have to get your data into a list, say `result`, and your headings into another list, say `header`. Then:

```
Panel[
 Print["The estimated solution is ", solucionestimada, 
  " where functions value is ", valorestimado];
 Style[
  TableForm[
   result,
   TableSpacing -> {1, 1},
   TableHeadings -> {None, 
     Style["" <> #, Bold, TextAlignment -> Right, 10] & /@ header},
   TableAlignments -> {".", Bottom}],
  14, FontFamily -> "Georgia"]
 ]
```

To obtain the list from your code, do away with the `Print` statements, and instead collect the data. As you requested, this is the code I used to generate `header` and `result`, but **please note that this was just a quick hack to get your code working the way I wanted it to** - this isn't how to write Mathematica code!

```
itmax = 10;
tolerancia = 0.2;
alfa = (-1 + Sqrt[5])/2;
ttheta[lambda_] = lambda^2 + 2*lambda;
a = -3;
b = 5;
La = a + (1 - alfa)*(b - a) // N;
Mu = a + alfa*(b - a) // N;
tthetaLa = ttheta[La];
tLacalc = "*";
tthetaMu = ttheta[Mu];
tMucalc = "*";
header = {"iteración-k", "a-k", "b-k", "Lambda-k", "Mu-k", 
   "theta(Lambda-k)", " ", "theta(Mu-k)", " "};
collected = Reap[
  Do[L = b - a;
   Sow[{i, a, b, La, Mu, tthetaLa, tLacalc , tthetaMu, tMucalc}];
   If[tthetaLa > tthetaMu, If[b - a < tolerancia, Break[]];
    a = La;
    La = Mu;
    Mu = a + alfa (b - a);
    tthetaLa = tthetaMu;
    tLacalc = " ";
    tthetaMu = ttheta[Mu];
    tMucalc = " ";
    , b = Mu;
    Mu = La;
    La = a + (1 - alfa) (b - a);
    tthetaMu = tthetaLa;
    tMucalc = " ";
    tthetaLa = ttheta[La];
    tLacalc = "*";],
   {i, 1, itmax}];
  solucionestimada = (Mu + La)/2;
  valorestimado = ttheta[solucionestimada];
  ]
result = Flatten[Rest[collected], 2];
```

This collects everything as you go, ready for the separate stage of formatting and presentation, once the calculation is finished. Another benefit of this is that you can spend hours playing with the formatting, without having to do all the calculations again... :)

If you want to play with `Grid`, you can get carried away and do stuff like this:

```
Panel[
 Grid[
  Prepend[result, header ],
  Spacings -> {0, 1},
  Alignment -> {".", Automatic},
  Background -> {None, {Lighter[Yellow, .9], 
    {White, Lighter[Blend[{Blue, Green}], .9]}}},
  Frame -> True,
  FrameStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[-10]]],
 Style[Row[{"The estimated solution is ", solucionestimada, 
" where functions value is ", valorestimado}], 16, Bold]]
```

(Odd that all the color and styling is in `Grid` but not `TableForm`...)

[image: grid table]

Comment: I think `Grid` ain´t half bad. Producing nice tables with TeX or (oh dear) Excel also takes a fair amount of work.

Comment: I couldn't get `TextAlignment` working here...

Comment: @YvesKlett You can do the `Grid` version... :)

Comment: ouch - that hurt :-P

Comment: @YvesKlett As you said, it ain't half bad :)

Comment: @cormullion I Love your answer. The only thing i can´t understand is to store the data in result, bacause i´m not used to do this with lists, and arrays. I know that is so simple.  I look at your lines REAP[..... SOW.....] but i can´t make that lines go well.      But Your answer is... the answer i needed. Thank You

Comment: @mika thanks. Ask a new (suitably simplified) question if you get stuck!

Comment: @cormullion i understant the global method, but i was trying and trying and can´t reach no result because, i don´t have variables like "header" or any other things. I can´t get any table... and your answer and the MrWizard are fantastics answers.    Could you give me the complete code? so i can get a result and "changing" things to learn in the table.  Thank You

Comment: @MikaIke no problem, but I was just trying to show one technique and hacked your code to do it. There could well be better ways to achieve your results with more elegant coding.

Comment: @MikaIke Oh, I see you've just got Mr.Wizard on the case. I needn't have bothered...

Comment: @cormullion THANK YOU..... finally i can view "your" table in my MAthemtica :-)  i´m happy  . Now i can "play" chaging things and understanding things.  Mr.Wizard &cormullion and cormullion & MrWizard solved perfectly my question. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 5):

The undocumented function `TableView` in version 9 (it exist in 8 too) looks quite close to Excel(and it has some basic Excel-like functions, try it out with a right click):

`TableView[RandomReal[1, {6, 6}]]`

[image]

, which would be a fine choice for lazy guys like me :D.

Comment: Just a note: `TableView` is notoriously unstable, you can easily crash the kernel fiddling with it, e.g. by editing a field. Until better integration (making it a proper, documented built-in) I wouldn't recommend using it.

Comment: What’s the status of this function now?  Is it suitable for heavy use?

Answer (score 3):

I give below the table I did some time ago. You only need to replace my table by yours, that has the same structure. Note that the first sublist in the list   "table" contains the titles of the columns in the resulting table, and the first elements of the other sublists are the titles of the lines. Play a bit with the colors to select ones according to your taste.

```
table = {{"Segment", 
    Column[{"Skin temperature [\[Degree]C]", 
      "@ cold stable conditions"}], 
    Column[{"Skin temperature [\[Degree]C]", 
      "@ warm stable conditions"}]},
   {"Forehead", 30.7, 36.5},
   {"Cheek", 27.7, 36.3},
   {"Front neck", 33.5, 36.8},
   {"Back neck", 34.5, 36.1},
   {"Chest", 30.9, 36.1},
   {"Back", 32.4, 36.3},
   {"Abdomen", 28.7, 36.2},
   {"Upper arm", 24.7, 36.4}};

Panel@Grid[table, Frame -> All, 
  Dividers -> Directive[Gray, Thickness[4]], 
  ItemSize -> {Automatic, 2}, 
  Background -> {None, {LightYellow, {LightBlue, LightOrange}}, 
    1 -> LightYellow}]
```

That is what should appear as the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank You very Much, i want to try and aunderstad the different options, but now my problem is that i don´t understand how i must modify my code, and how to collect data with Reap Sow to show them in a table.